# Error when tring to install package like this "@u-wave/react-youtube": "github:u-wave/react-youtube"

Tags: ubuntu, npm

OS: Ubuntu 18.04. npm version: 6.14.2. node version: 8.16.2

I know that there is no problem with library, look like it's about npm version(I read it in one of the github issues)

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
  "@u-wave/react-youtube": "github:u-wave/react-youtube",
  ...
```

**Error in console** when running `sudo npm i`

```
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 1> 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall /home/sabit/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-2c59db53/node_modules/core-js-pure
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > @u-wave/react-youtube@0.7.1 prepare /home/sabit/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-2c59db53
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > npm run build
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > @u-wave/react-youtube@0.7.1 build /home/sabit/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-2c59db53
npm ERR! prepareGitDep > rollup -c
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 2> npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! prepareGitDep /home/sabit/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-2c59db53/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/loadConfigFile.js:484
npm ERR! prepareGitDep         ? (await import(url.pathToFileURL(fileName).href)).default
npm ERR! prepareGitDep                  ^^^^^^
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sabit/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-2c59db53/node_modules/rollup/dist/bin/rollup:21:25)
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! @u-wave/react-youtube@0.7.1 build: `rollup -c`
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! Failed at the @u-wave/react-youtube@0.7.1 build script.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR!     /home/sabit/.npm/_logs/2020-05-19T13_32_21_513Z-debug.log
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! @u-wave/react-youtube@0.7.1 prepare: `npm run build`
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! Failed at the @u-wave/react-youtube@0.7.1 prepare script.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! prepareGitDep npm ERR!     /home/sabit/.npm/_logs/2020-05-19T13_32_21_595Z-debug.log
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: @u-wave/react-youtube@github:u-wave/react-youtube.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sabit/.npm/_logs/2020-05-19T13_32_22_710Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone explain this behavior of npm?

Comment: Is that specific library actually designed to be installed from source code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, no it's just a public repo. Just it look like there is no problem in other teammates(MacOS). You can check library there https://www.npmjs.com/package/@u-wave/react-youtube

Comment: But if you look at what's on GitHub vs. what's in the package on NPM, the `dist/` directory is missing. Many packages need to be *built*, you can't install them straight from source.